# Combining Groups of Incrementing Digits with Regex

Tags: regex, replace, increment, pcre

Hi StackOverflow Community!

I am writing a catch-all solution to naming conventions with course codes and combining them. A simple example of a course code looks like this: 00001

What I have currently is a set of course codes in a string. Something like this:

00001_00002_00003_00005_00008_00009

I am still new to using regex, but is it possible to make an expression that checks if

Each code between the delimiter is incremented by one of its previous codes.
Then, it takes the first and the last of those codes, removes the middle codes, and replaces it with "-"
So, for the same set of codes, I would get:

00001-00003_00005_00008-00009

Even if the code came back looking like this: 00001_-_00003_00005_00008_-_00009, I could finagle the string after the fact to replace '_-_' with '-'.

All of the codes are already in incrementing order so it would just have to iterate through from left to right.

So far what I have (I know it's pretty bare-bones): https://regex101.com/r/Yb1gSq/2/

Anyone have any pointers? Or should I be looking for a different solution other than regex?

Comment: Maybe try: https://regex101.com/r/Yb1gSq/3

Comment: That's a bit closer to what I am looking for, but can regex look at a group and match +1 at a time, not just any incrementing digit?

Comment: You would likely need to code the incrementing portion in the language you are using as regex doesn't really do math.

Comment: ok, I think I can accomplish that, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for regex and it's [better to pose the problem itself without presupposing a solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What language are you working in?